# Evaluate $C_f(n)={1\over4n+{1\over12n+{1\over 20n+{1\over 28n+\cdots}}}}$

Tags: continued-fractions

Does this continued fraction, $C_f(n)$ has a closed form?

$$C_f(n)={1\over4n+{1\over12n+{1\over 20n+{1\over 28n+\cdots}}}}\tag1$$

$n\ge1.$

Yes?

So I did some mathematical experimental for a while and sort came up with this as a closed form

$${e+1\over e-1}-{2\over e-1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^{j+1}\sqrt[2n]{e^j}\right)\tag2$$
 but how can we show that $(2)$ is correct?

Comment: what is the pattern on the coefficients in the the Continued Fraction? For example, what comes after 28? Appears to be $8k+4$

Comment: the pattern would be $4(1,3,5,7,9,11,...)$

Comment: First, cancel some signs to get $$\frac{e+1}{e-1}+\frac{2}{e-1}\sum_j (-1)^je^{j/(2n)}$$ Then write $\frac{e+1}{e-1}=1+\frac{2}{e-1}$ to get an equivalent formula: $$1+\frac{2}{e-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}e^{j/(2n)}$$

Comment: And then $\sum_{j=0}^{2n-1}e^{i/(2n)}=\frac{e-1}{e^{1/(2n)}-1}$, so you get a much simpler formula: $$1+\frac{2}{e^{1/(2n)}-1}=\frac{e^{1/(2n)} + 1}{e^{1/(2n)}-1}$$ Not sure if that helps

Comment: Might be worth noting that $\tanh(1/n) = [0; n, 3n, 5n, 7n, ...]$ so that $\tanh(1) = [0; 1, 3, 5, 7, ...]$ which looks like the form Thomas got. Quick Wikipedia reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Regular_patterns_in_continued_fractions). See also [this Wolfram functions page](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tanh/10/).

Comment: Not just worth notice, that gives us the exact answer, since $\tanh(1/(4n))$ is the inverse of what we want.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews haha, yes, I know. I was leaving some work to the OP :)

Comment: Whivh is the same as my simplification, since $$\tanh(1/(4n))=\frac{e^{1/(2n)}-1}{e^{1/(2n)}+1}$$

Comment: thank you guys, got it